# Can't see open ports of Docker PostgreSQL container?

Tags: macos, docker, terminal

I have a container running with PostgreSQL, expose port 5432, but can not find them when running `lsof -Pn -i4` or  `netstat | grep 5432`.

I can however connect with the database through my Spring Boot application.

Why can't I see the open ports on my local machine of the docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `netstat -a` it will show all active connections i.e. the ports that are acting as both server (some services are listening to these ports for connections from a different machine/process) and established (connections are established on these ports regardless of the fact the host/a service can be a server or client)